# php simple xpath question

Tags: php, xpath

I have this div:

```
<div class="product-name">Product1</div>
```

I also have this div:

```
<div class="product-name gold">Product2</div>
```

How can I alter this xpath query to get whatever divs which **contains** product-name? Instead of getting an exact match.

```
/html/body//div[@class='product-name']
```

I googled it, but all I could find is how to use `contains` when searching for a value within a node, and not an attribute.

**EDIT**
[image]

Comment: please provide your source document.

Comment: @Alex, why do you need to see any source other than what I have provided?

Comment: Valid XML should have only one root node. Wrap your divs with `<html><body>..</body></html>` and everything will be ok.

Comment: because there may be problem. Your XPath testing tool allows not valid XML documents :) While the one I'm referencing in my comment produces `XML Error: System.Xml.XmlException: There are multiple root elements. Line 4, position 2. at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)` when the same document is supplied.

Comment: Check my answer for the well known and proper way to express this in XPath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`contains()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-contains):

```
/html/body//div[contains(@class, 'product-name')]
```

**Update:**

As [@Alejandro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/357812/alejandro) points out in his comment, this would also match any class that *contains* `product-name`. [See his answer for a XPath 1.0 solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5304791/php-simple-xpath-question/5305541#5305541).

If you use XPath 2.0, you could also do this:

```
/html/body//div[exists(index-of(tokenize(@class, "\s+"), "product-name"))]
```

Comment: Doesn't pick up the second div, also checked here http://emdin-here.ru/r/xpath_checker/

Comment: @OrW: This solution is correct (as per your question). If it does not work for you, your question does not represent your problem.

Comment: @OrW: It works for me. Are you passing the right document? If you are using the exact XPath above, the document must include `html` and `body` nodes. Or remove `/html/body` from the path and try again.

Comment: @OrW: You provided a not valid XML document. A XML document has always only **one** root node. Put both divs and a `<root>` element or in `<html><body>...`.

Comment: @OrW: Your're welcome :) To be honest, I did the same mistake ;) :D

Comment: @Felix Kling: Do note that this expression would select also `<div class="no-product-name gold">Whatever</div>`

Comment: @Felix Kling: You can perform existencial comparison against sequence in XPath 2.0. That would be `/html/body//div[tokenize(@class, '\s+') = 'product-name']`

Answer (score 2):

The classic XPath 1.0 answer for this existencial test on sequence is:

```
/html/body//div[
   contains(
      concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),
      ' product-name '
   )
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`/html/body//div[contains(@class,'product-name')]`

Attributes are also nodes, they are called attribute nodes.

Comment: For some reason, that still does not pick up the ``product-name gold``

Comment: please verify that your code is correct. The `//div` part is correct and meets your requirements. Verify that not matching div is descendant of the `/html/body`. You can verify this XPath f.i. at http://www.xmlme.com/XpathTool.aspx